# How does Java detects mouse movement

Tags: java, events, customization, listeners

We know that JComponent has several methods to add various listeners. One example is the `addMouseMotionListneer()`.

Within a `MouseMotionListener`, there are 2 methods to be overridden:

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){}
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){}
```

Whenever the mouse is moved, `mouseMoved()` will be invoked.

**My question is**:

1) How does Java detects mouse movement? Is there a lot of lower level stuff (like communicating with mouse drivers..etc) where Java is doing behind our back?

2) I know if we want to detect mouse movements, we simply could use the event listeners in the `awt`. But is there any possibilities we could write our own listeners to detect mouse movement? Or we can simply forget about it as it is mission impossible?

Comment: Why would this question attract down votes? Can the down voter leave a comment why you down voted so I can improve the question?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the event listeners of awt but that are not platform independent. 
ON some platforms it will not work fine.

Yes could write our own listeners to detect mouse movement by implementing  MouseMotionListener or MouseListener interface and add your custom methods for some special events

OR

you have to follow delegate event model. So create a class MyMouseEvent , MyMouse and interface MyMouseListner

```
interface MyMouseListener{
   public void clicked();
}

Class MyMouse{
MyMouseListener m;
public void register(MyMouseListener  m){
 this.m=m;
  }
}

class MyMouseEvent{
  //use in case of multiple event listener   
}
```

Then registered by creating object

```
MyMouse m = new MyMouse().register(new MyMouseListener(){
public void clicked(){
   // your code here
}
})
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply, but I already mentioned in my question I am not asking how to do that. I am asking how to write listeners *without* implementing any of the interface given by Java.

Comment: I already tried something like this quite some time ago, it won't work because making a listener to work is not as simple as just creating a mouseListener instance in the class. How would it triggers the clicked() `in your case` when mouse clicks? There must be a way to detect a click in the first place right? So, that was my question. How do we detect mouse move ourselves without using Java interface.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be what you need:

```
 import java.awt.MouseInfo;
 import java.awt.GridLayout;
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
 import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

 import javax.swing.*;

 public class mice {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    while(true){
        //Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("("+MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x+", "+MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y+")");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, what about detecting mouse movement. Is it possible to do it without using the given Java interface?

Comment: You can port some c/c++ libraries to java and use them for communicating with lower level components. As far as I know java is pretty limited when it comes to interacting with anything outside of a jframe.